# Order by date with limit entries per 24h

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, mapping

considering the following data as input:

```
[
  {
    date: 1612506159000, // 05 feb 2021 14:22
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612507239000, // 05 feb 2021 14:40
    id: "3NCzApG3ka4tvDuKX8HxnJtXe7eJw5PmdVt",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612514439000, // 05 feb 2021 16:40
    id: "3NCzApG3ka4tvDuKX8HxnJtXe7eJw5PmdVt",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612510119000, // 05 feb 2021 15:28
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612501359000, // 05 feb 2021 13:02
    id: "3MtHDo9NrDWWadvmCrCT9G7tLJ4wjCFQUDc",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612522539000, // 05 feb 2021 18:55
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612523139000, // 05 feb 2021 19:05
    id: "3NCzApG3ka4tvDuKX8HxnJtXe7eJw5PmdVt",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612612959000, // 06 feb 2021 20:02
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  }
]
```

How could i filter it to have it meeting the following:

- Ordered by date
- Only 2 entries per addr per 24h based on timestamp

Example of the output:

```
[
  {
    date: 1612514439000, // 05 feb 2021 16:40
    id: "3NCzApG3ka4tvDuKX8HxnJtXe7eJw5PmdVt",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612510119000, // 05 feb 2021 15:28
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612501359000, // 05 feb 2021 13:02
    id: "3MtHDo9NrDWWadvmCrCT9G7tLJ4wjCFQUDc",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612522539000, // 05 feb 2021 18:55
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612523139000, // 05 feb 2021 19:05
    id: "3NCzApG3ka4tvDuKX8HxnJtXe7eJw5PmdVt",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  },
  {
    date: 1612612959000, // 06 feb 2021 20:02
    id: "3N1wPgHFtezmRVBaqoojP8XJwTkark4hbif",
    cid: "oaz5u/display.png"
  }
]
```

To order by date i do the following:

```
  // data is the object with the data as shared in the post
  let orderedData = Object.values(data).sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
  });
```

But i don't know how to keep only 2 per addr per 24h timestamp.

Hope this is clearer than my previous attempt requesting help for it :)

Comment: What is "addr"? `id`?

Comment: And do you want the first two for each addr per date, or the last two, or any two?

Comment: can you also post your required output format so we can understand clearly what exactly you need !

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, addr is the unique id of the user.
I want the last two for each addr per 24h based on date
Output ideally is the same object as input but filtered

Comment: Sorry i realise my answer isn't clear, addr = id and represent a user.